# About $\lambda$-saturated ideals defined through a $\lambda$-cc forcing

Tags: set-theory, forcing

In Kanamori's "The Higher Infinite" (2nd ed.) there is Lemma 17.7. When I first went through the proof it seemed obvious, but now that I'm reviewing it, I get confused.

---

The lemma states that if $\kappa,\lambda$ are regular cardinals, $\Bbb P$ is a $\lambda$-cc forcing and
\begin{align*}
\Bbb P\Vdash\dot J\text{ is a $\check V$-$\lambda$-saturated ideal over }\kappa,
\end{align*}
then $I=\{X\subset \kappa\mid {\Bbb P}\Vdash\check X\in\dot J\}$ is a $\lambda$-saturated ideal over $\kappa$. Here $\check V$ names the ground model, and $V$-$\lambda$-saturated means being $\lambda$-saturated if we restrict our attention to only families of sets in $V$.

The proof rests on the assertion that if we have a family $\{X_\alpha\mid \alpha<\lambda\}\subseteq \mathcal P(\kappa)$ such that for each $\alpha$ we have $X_\alpha\notin I$, then $\Bbb P\Vdash\left|\{\alpha<\lambda\mid \check X_\alpha\notin \dot J\}\right|=\lambda.$ The proof of this assertion is by contradiction, namely, if this were not the case, then there would be $\gamma<\lambda$ such that $\Bbb P\Vdash\{\alpha<\lambda\mid X_\alpha\notin \dot J\}\subseteq \check\gamma$ by $\Bbb P$ being $\lambda$-cc and $\lambda$ being regular.

---

I'm not understanding this step. If $\Bbb P\not\Vdash\left|\{\alpha<\lambda\mid \check X_\alpha\notin \dot J\}\right|=\lambda,$ then at best we can conclude that there is **some** $p\in\Bbb P$ such that $p\Vdash\left|\{\alpha<\lambda\mid \check X_\alpha\notin \dot J\}\right|<\lambda.$ However, for the contradiction to arise, this has to happen for **every** $p\in \Bbb P$. Why does it follow from the assumption towards contradiction that there is no $p'\in \Bbb P$ such that $p'\Vdash\left|\{\alpha<\lambda\mid \check X_\alpha\notin \dot J\}\right|=\lambda$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can correct Kanamori's argument as follows: we claim that *there is $p\in\mathbb{P}$* such that
$$p\Vdash |\{\alpha<\lambda \mid \check{X}_\alpha \notin \dot{J}\}|=\lambda.$$

Suppose not, we have $1\Vdash |\{\alpha<\lambda \mid \check{X}_\alpha \notin \dot{J}\}|<\lambda$. Since $\mathbb{P}$ is $\lambda$-c.c. and $\lambda$ is regular, $\mathbb{P}$ preserves $\lambda$ is a regular cardinal, so we can find $q$ and $\gamma<\lambda$ such that
$$q\Vdash |\{\alpha<\lambda \mid \check{X}_\alpha \notin \dot{J}\}|\subseteq \check{\gamma}.$$

By using $\mathbb{P}$ being $\lambda$-c.c. and the regularity of $\lambda$, we may assume that $q=1$. (Here we use a tedious maximal antichain argument.) Now we have $1\Vdash \check{X}_\gamma\in \dot{J}$, a contradiction.

Since $\mathbb{P}$ forces $\dot{J}$ is $\check{V}$-$\lambda$-saturated, we can find $q\le p$ and $\alpha<\beta<\lambda$ such that $q\Vdash \check{X}_\alpha\cap\check{X}_\beta\notin \dot{J}$. That is, $1\not\Vdash \check{X}_\alpha\cap\check{X}_\beta\in\dot{J}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I believe that by regularity of $\lambda$ and $\lambda$-cc, we may take $q=p$, and if I'm not mistaken you have the negations flipped around in the last sentence. I'm still not convinced here, though. We now have $p\Vdash \check X_\gamma\in \dot J$, hence $p\not\Vdash \check X_\gamma\notin \dot J$, from which we can go back up to get $\not\Vdash_{\Bbb P}\check X_\gamma\notin \dot J$, but this does not imply that $\Vdash_{\Bbb P}\check X_\gamma\in \dot J$, hence we cannot conclude $X_\gamma\in I$ yet to get a contradiction.

Comment: @Vsotvep You do not need to equate $p$ and $q$. We have $q\Vdash \check{X}_\gamma\notin \dot{J}$ by my argument. Since $X_\gamma\in I$, $1\Vdash \check{X}_\gamma\in \dot{J}$, which implies $q\Vdash \check{X}_\gamma\in \dot{J}$.

Comment: @Vsotvep You do not necessarily stick to the first paragraph in my answer. (Yes, it is easy to misunderstand, but I had no idea how to put it a better way.) I just want to mention that many set theorists use notations loosely because of that reason.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still confused. First, I think we don't need the $\lambda$-cc to find such $q\leq p$: $p$ already forces that there exists such a $\gamma$ by regularity, and then we can take $q$ to be any condition deciding $\gamma$. Implicitly by it being mentioned as a property for $\Bbb P$, I expect $\lambda$-cc to be necessary. Second, $q$ forces that almost all $X_\alpha\in \dot J$, in particular $q\Vdash \check X_\gamma\in \dot J$, and not $q\Vdash \check X_\gamma\notin \dot J$, like you claim. Third, $X_\gamma\in I$ is not true: the $X_\alpha$ are chosen to be *not* in $I$.

Comment: As for the first part of your comment, I agree with this, but I always believed that restricting the forcing is dual to arguing with denseness: by moving to a stronger condition (from within a dense subset of the forcing) we get more information. Then by arbitrariness of our choice of stronger condition, whatever we decided is true for the full forcing. My problem here is that the $p$ that we restrict to is not arbitrary, in the sense that the set of such $p$ is not necessarily dense.

Comment: @Vsotvep You are right, I was confused. I will come back after thinking about it.

Comment: @Vsotvep I fixed the error in Kanamori's proof. My previous comment could be out-of-point, so I removed it.

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem. Thanks for the help!